# emacs and gdb-many-windows

Tags: emacs

i am new to emacs. In many site there is a opition to set gdb-many-windows which actually
split the window like

```
 |   GUD buffer (I/O of GDB)      |   Locals/Registers buffer      |

 |   Primary Source buffer        |   I/O buffer for debugged pgm  |

 |   Stack buffer                 |   Breakpoints/Threads buffer   |
```

Whenever i try to do
"M-x gdb-many-window"  it does not recognize it.
"M-x gdb" et al works well but not "M-x gdb-many-window"?

Does anyone have faced this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [this](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/02/fancy-debugging-with-gdb.html) and [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DebuggingWithEmacs).  `M-x gdb-many-windows` works after `M-x gdb` and the *gud* window is in focus.  Your question suggests that you are trying for `M-x gdb-many-windows` before `M-x gdb`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. however i am doing M-x gdb-many-windows after the call to M-x gdb and then gdb ./a.out

Comment: Also when i try "M-x gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello #" also does not work. is there any init file i need to modify.Whatever mentioned in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DebuggingWithEmacs does not work as it is for me

Comment: Why are you doing `M-x gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello #`?  Are you trying to compile?  You need to write a `Makefile` and do `M-x compile` in order to invoke the Makefile.  What does not work as it is given on the wiki?  What are you expecting to happen?  What are you doing?  What is actually happening?

Comment: Thanks Vpit for a quick reply. What i am trying to do is to do some learn c debugging with emacs (Earlier i was using visual studio). My first problem is M-x gdb-many-windows does't  for me. I did: 1)  M-x gdb 2) Minibuffer says "Run gdb (like this): gdb ./a.out" 3) i pressed return key 4) i tried M-x gdb-many-windows in the minbuffer  but it didn't recognize it.Also "selecting the checkbox on the menubar (Gud -> GDB-UI-> Display other windows)" is also not working as mentioned in http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7876

Comment: OK, start gdb as `M-x gdb` and then supply it the binary file to be debugged in the minibuffer or simply hit the enter key to get into the *gud* buffer.  In the *gud* you can use all gdb commands such as `(gdb) "file <file to be debugged>"` to load the file for example.  Then do `M-x gdb-many-windows`.  Then debug.  But you should learn gdb commands.  To leverage Emacs' power, it really helps learning its key bindings, in this case, with regards to gdb mode.  Also, Emacs' *gud* can handle other debuggers as well.

Comment: Hi Vpit, Thanks you for explaining this to me in detail. i exactly followed the procedure. All went as expected till (gdb) file <file_to_be_debugged> . After that M-x gdb-many-windows says [No Match] with a beep sound.

Comment: Can you tell which version of Emacs you use and on which operating system?  What I told works fine on my Debian testing with Emacs 23.2.1.  Also, can you show the error message you get upon repeating the steps from start after enabling debugging by `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`?

Comment: I am using emacs 21.3.3 Redhat Enterprise Linux WS release 4.Also i did M-x toggle-debug-on-error and repeated the steps.All the step before "M-x gdb-many-windows" went well. the problem is M-x gdb-many-windows says "[No match]"

Comment: I can't find out exactly in which release of Emacs it was introduced.  But surely emacs21.4.1 on the RHEL servers here does not have gdb-many-windows so your emacs21.3.3 is not having it unless it is installed separately.  You might need to install a newer gud.  Or, a newer emacs.

Comment: vpit thank you very much for your help. Without your help it would not have been possible for a new beginner like me to debug this situation. Thanks a lot. I will try to update the emacs and let you know the if it works

Comment: vpit i updated my emacs to 23.2.2. Now the gdb-many-windows works. But i am now facing the new problem that the in the gud buffer windows the (gdb) prompt whatever i write it is not executed. No error message is thrown the cursor went to new line and sits there ideal. Do you know what it might be.

Comment: I am using gdb 7.2 and gcc 3.4.4

Comment: No error messages?  How do you start gdb and what are you doing from there?  The commands, keystrokes?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the scenario you explain.  Debugging with gdb under emacs works smoothly here.  If you can explain what you do to get the results you speak of, it can help.

Comment: hi vpit, thanks for the quick reply. yes it does not dump any error message however using --annotate=3 after thing work well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495702/using-gdb-in-emacs-v23 helped me fixed it. Do you have any suggestion for a quick gdb tutorial

Comment: Great that it works! :)  As for learning gdb, I learn it with the help command in gdb or looking up the web for how to do something with gdb.