# emacs gud window use

Tags: emacs, gud

How do I customize which window GUD will use when i issue commands - 'up', 'down', etc ?  It seems to use an arbitrary window, sometimes even the window with gdb in it - I want to be able to specify a specific window to be used.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? Are you running the debugger with gdb or gud-gdb? Have you customized any relevant variables?

Comment: emacs 23.1.1, running debugger with M-x gdb.  Have not customized any variables related to GUD/GDB.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered borrowing the key bindings mentioned in the following question?
[Emacs, switch to previous window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91071/emacs-switch-active-window)

This question implies that *GUD* steps on some things if you don't add a parameter. Maybe your command bindings are being affected similiarly.
[Using gdb in Emacs 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495702/using-gdb-in-emacs-23)

I asked a buddy of mine about this issue and here is what he said.

> Well, we used xemacs and so it's not exactly apples to apples here.  I
>   do have gnu-emacs installed on cygwin and I can't replicate his
>   problem.  I think he definitely needs to list a version # for emacs
>   and the version # for all his installed packages.
>
> When you press up/down it calls 'previous-line' and 'next-line'
>   respectively which both move the cursor in the default buffer.  The
>   only thing I can think is that he has something running that switches
>   buffers (lisp 'set-buffer') temporarily and maybe doesn't set it back
>   or errors b/f restoring the buffer?  Better to use
>   'with-current-buffer' (or one of the other with-* forms) that saves
>   the current state of the ui runs your lisp code and restores the ui
>   state.